Leaflet Maps and Google Mutant
Install 1 -

Install 2 -

Used this for a long time, years now, and now all of a sudden it doesn't show up anymore.  No errors, just doesn't show up in my system anymore.  No google base-maps.  I have good credentials.  That has happened before, change a card due to loss, get pinged on no payment, this is strange though.  Leaflet 1.7.0 - Been working since.  I've not touched the code.  I don't understand.
error---
map.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Spread syntax 
requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function
at qwa (map.js:37:176)
at Lxa.changed (map.js:107:360)
at al (js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…Yg&ver=6.5.2:196:59)
at _.Zk.bindTo (js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…g&ver=6.5.2:334:152)
at lya.Rxa [as PE] (map.js:71:23)
at js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…Yg&ver=6.5.2:265:78
qwa @   map.js:37
changed @   map.js:107
al  @   js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…R37Yg&ver=6.5.2:196
_.Zk.bindTo @   js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…R37Yg&ver=6.5.2:334
Rxa @   map.js:71
(anonymous) @   js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…R37Yg&ver=6.5.2:265
await in (anonymous)        
handleMouseUp_  @   unknown
Promise.then        
Zn  @   js?key=AIzaSyDIn3Uui…R37Yg&ver=6.5.2:264
_initMutant @   Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js?ver=6.5.2:173
(anonymous) @   Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js?ver=6.5.2:62
handleMouseUp_  @   unknown
Promise.then        
onAdd   @   Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js?ver=6.5.2:58
_layerAdd   @   Layer.js:114
whenReady   @   Map.js:1465
addLayer    @   Layer.js:176
addTo   @   Layer.js:52
(anonymous) @   post.php?post=3182&action=edit:11771
dispatch    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…e,utils&ver=6.5.2:2
v.handle    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…e,utils&ver=6.5.2:2
handleMouseUp_  @   unknown
---end error

// Set up map layers
var roads = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    type: 'roadmap' // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
});

var satellite = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    type: 'satellite'   // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
});
var hybrid = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    type: 'hybrid'  // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
});


The demo at https://ivansanchez.gitlab.io/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/demo.html still works, so you'll have to be more specific.

Interesting indeed.  I should have checked!  Haven't updated leaflet in awhile, nor google mutant if it needs it.  So very strange.. Nothing in code base as been touched.

Please see above error and suggest as you can.  Please

Please see above error and suggest as you can.  Please, The error above only happens on selection of the google type base-maps and happens on every single install, some have not been touched in a long time... It has to be a change at google or something? What are your thoughts??

So it just started working again out of nowhere.
No idea what the hell happened.  Had to be something at Google servers.  This was the strangest thing I've seen in a long time.
